# HTML5 element is being removed when switching between visual and text editor

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using WordPress to code a site using hand-coded HTML, which I paste into the page editor of WordPress. But when I load that page using the built-in visual editor, tinyMCE is removing the `<main>` element from my markup and replaces it with `&nbsp;`

I'm familiar with users experiencing frustration with tinyMCE/WordPress injecting `<p>` elements or stripping empty tags, etc. But this one really stumps me. Any ideas?

Comment: it tends to do that :(  its better to use wp editor just for text or remove the visual tab and use page templates = http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-custom-page-template/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the cleanup which TinyMCE does.

If you have edit permission you should add `<main>` as

[valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements) or [extended_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements).

You can set

```
valid_elements : '*[*]',
```

to allow all html tags.

You can also set `verify_html` to `false`.